# Second Monitor not displaying anything 22.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

[Pic of Settings->Display w/ both monitors available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQxhx.png)

I built my first PC and decided to make it a dual boot for some Security classes coming up. When I initially installed Ubuntu it was displaying my second monitor, but while adjusting the settings it stopped working. I can run windows 11 with both monitors, but when I change the settings in Ubuntu it will cycle power to the monitor in question, and then it goes right back to sleep.

I am running an amd gpu (most answers are for the nvidia cards) and have verified that my sys is running the right drivers. My output on xrandr --listmonitors is:
Monitors: 1
0: +*XWAYLAND0 1920/530x1080/300+0+0 XWAYLAND0

But if it only has one monitor available, why is it showing them both listed in Settings->Display?

Comment: You have selected the single display tab, select join displays and position them the way you want.

Comment: That's what I'm saying, when I select that tab and hit apply, it cycles power to the monitor for a brief second and then shuts back down and resumes single monitor ops...

Answer (score 1):

I have absolutely no idea what actually happened, but after too many hours of messing with this it worked. My computer 100% recognized there was a second monitor in the settings shown above, but when I ran xrandr --listmonitors it said there was only 1 monitor. Even at initial sign in the second monitor was powered on, but got "no signal" after sign in. I was, for no apparent reason, finally able to put it into mirror mode, then Join. I don't know, but I learned a lot for no reason, so there's that! lol.